# Why are all my child components re-rendering despite having keys?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, performance

I was playing around with react-dev-tools chrome extension and found out that all my components are re-rendering.

**App.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Header from './components/molecules/Header/Header';
// import { colorListGenerator } from './core-utils/helpers';
import ColorPalette from './components/organisms/ColorPalette/ColorPalette';

export const colorListGenerator = (n) => {
  let colorArray = []
  for(let i=0; i<n; i++) {
      let randomColor = '#'+Math.floor(Math.random()*16777215).toString(16);
      let id="id" + Math.random().toString(16).slice(2)
      console.log(typeof(id), id)
      let color = {
          id: id,
          hex: randomColor
      }
      colorArray.push(color);
  }
  return colorArray
}

const App = () => {
  const colors=colorListGenerator(10);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Header/>
      <ColorPalette colorPalette={colors} />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**ColorPalette.js**

```
/* eslint-disable eqeqeq */
import React from 'react';
import Color from '../../atoms/Color';
import './ColorPalette.css';

const ColorPalette = ({ colorPalette }) => {

    const [colors, setColors] = React.useState(colorPalette);

    // const handleColorClick = (event) => {
    //     const id = event.currentTarget.getAttribute('id')
    //     const index = colors.findIndex(item => item.id == id);
    //     setColors(colors.filter(item => item.id != id))
    // }

    const deleteItem = (id) => {
        setColors(colors.filter(item => item.id != id))
    }

    return (
        <div className={'colorPalette'}>
            {colors && colors.map((color, index) => {
                // const key = index
                const key = color.id
                return <Color
                key={key}
                color={color.hex}
                colorKey={key} 
                handleColorClick = {() => {deleteItem(color.id)}}
                /> })}
        </div>
    )
}

// export default React.memo(ColorPalette);
export default ColorPalette;
```

**Color.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import './Color.css';
import deleteIcon from '../../../delete-icon.png'

const Color = ({ color, colorKey, handleColorClick }) => {
    return (
        <div className="color"
            style={{ backgroundColor: color }}
            // no need to mention key here
            // key={colorKey}
            id={colorKey}
            onClick={handleColorClick} >
            <p> {colorKey} </p>
            <img src={deleteIcon}
                alt={'delete'}
                className="delete"
            />
        </div>
    )
}

// export default React.memo(Color);
export default Color;
```

When I use the profiler to check why all my 'Color' components have re-rendered after deleting a single item, it complains that handleColorClick prop has changed. I changed the deleteItem to handleColorClick which isn't an arrow function, but the result is the same. I'm also passing unique ids. Interestingly, when I pass `const key = Math.random()` instead of `const key = color.id` my Color components are not rerendering. So it has something to do with the keys. I want to understand why my components are rerendering when I pass unique ids as keys.

Comment: @JMadelaine I removed the randomly generated ids and added some hardcoded unique ids, all my Color components are still re-rendering.

Comment: How do you define "re-rendering"? Is it just the render cycle, or do you mean updated in the DOM?

Comment: I meant another render cycle

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way a React functional component will be prevented from rerendering is by using [`React.memo`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactmemo) to memoize the component. Memoization here means that if the component's props do not change - they are strictly equivalent to each other using the `===` operator - then the component's last render output will be re-used instead of rerendering the entire component.

However, `React.memo` itself gets tricky when you're talking about props that are object or functions - values for which the strict `===` comparison checks referential equality. That means that for functions like `deleteItem` need to use something like [`React.useCallback`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecallback) to memoize the references themselves so that they themselves do not change between renders, which will trip up `React.memo` and lead to rerenders in situations where intuitively it seems like it shouldn't.

As you can see, it quickly starts to get quite complicated, as you try to keep track of memoizing your functions, your objects, your components, etc.

And really, what's the point?

The performance gains you get from memoization - if they even materialize - are miniscule. This is a classic case of premature optimization, sometimes called the "[root of all evil](https://stackify.com/premature-optimization-evil/)" because of what an unnecessary time sink it is, for little to no gain, and the cost of added complexity.

React itself in its optimized production build is insanely fast, good at resolving diffs, and in most cases could rerender your entire app dozens of times per second without any perceivable slowdown. You should ONLY start optimizing your app with things like memoization when you have ACTUAL, MEASURABLE impacts to performance that you need to address.

In short, *you do not need to worry about "unnecessary" rerenders.*

I'll say it again for emphasis:

DO NOT WORRY ABOUT "UNNECESSARY" RERENDERS.

Seriously.

PS: The reason using a random value for `key` makes it seem like unnecessary rerenders are eliminated is because every time a component renders it is literally a brand new instance of that component, not the same component being rerendered. React uses the `key` prop under the hood to track which component is which between renders. If that value is unreliable, it means that React is literally rendering NEW components every time. You're basically destroying all the old components and recreating them from scratch, albeit with the same props or whatever, but make no mistake, they are NOT the same components between renders. (Even their internal state including hooks will be erased)

Comment: Yes, React.memo is solving the problem. But, I want to understand why giving the list items a random key is also solving the problem and why my unique ids are not sufficient as keys. Also, the performance gains from memoization are huge in some cases, maybe not in this case.

Comment: It's difficult to know what you mean by "solving the problem" or how you are measuring renders without more detail. As I explain in my answer, random keys will literally cause all components to be destroyed and recreated between renders. So it is not solving anything, performance-wise, and in fact will make it worse.

Comment: yes, you were right, random keys are actually creating new instances of that component, that's why I couldn't see it in the renders and yes using random keys IS MAKING IT MUCH WORSE. Thanks a ton!

Comment: @nymphadora If your question has been answered, please mark the appropriate answer as "accepted" to mark this issue as resolved. That helps everyone focus on the questions on this site that still need attention. :)

Comment: I understand and accept your answer except for "which will trip up React.memo" part. A combination of React.memo and useCallback have solved the problem for me. So, I'm not exactly sure what you meant by tripping up React.Memo - it is working as expected. And yes, optimizing, in this case, is not advisable. I was just playing around to have a clearer understanding of optimization techniques. Also, I strongly believe that using React doesn't magically make our app faster(from my own personal experience).

Comment: @nymphadora cool we’re totally on the same page then, I only meant that useCallback and useMemo are not sufficient independently, they must be used together. Apologies for belaboring the point about premature optimization, I do not mean to patronize but only dissuade people from worrying too much about optimization unless they really need to. :)

Answer (score 1):

As per what you said `handleColorClick` prop has changed, which is why the components are getting re-rendered. Since you are using functional component and hooks in the component, when the component is getting re-rendered the function `handleColorClick` is redefined again and the reference is getting changed. That's the reason why the components are getting re-rendered even though you pass unique ids as keys.

In order to avoid that you can use `useCallback` hook which will help you not to get a new function reference unless there's a change in the dependencies provided to the `useCallback` hook

```js
/* eslint-disable eqeqeq */
import React, {useCallback} from 'react';
import Color from '../../atoms/Color';
import './ColorPalette.css';

const ColorPalette = ({ colorPalette }) => {

    const [colors, setColors] = React.useState(colorPalette);

    // const handleColorClick = (event) => {
    //     const id = event.currentTarget.getAttribute('id')
    //     const index = colors.findIndex(item => item.id == id);
    //     setColors(colors.filter(item => item.id != id))
    // }

    const deleteItem = useCallback((id) => {
        setColors(colors.filter(item => item.id != id))
    }, [])

    return (
        <div className={'colorPalette'}>
            {colors && colors.map((color, index) => {
                // const key = index
                const key = color.id
                return <Color
                key={key}
                color={color.hex}
                colorKey={key} 
                handleColorClick = {() => {deleteItem(color.id)}}
                /> })}
        </div>
    )
}

// export default React.memo(ColorPalette);
export default ColorPalette;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, I tried using useCallback but it isn't solving the issue. I don't know the reason for that and React.memo is helping in avoiding unnecessary renders.

Comment: React.memo worked because, When a component is wrapped in React.memo(), React renders the component and memoizes the result. Before the next render, if the new props are the same, React reuses the memoized result skipping the next rendering. For a deeper understanding of React.memo, have a look at [this](https://dmitripavlutin.com/use-react-memo-wisely/)

Comment: A combination of useCallback() for the function and React.memo() for the Child component has solved the issue. Thanks for your answer, I now have a clear understanding of useCallback(), React.Memo() and useMemo()